# Android Studio - No SDK Found - Setup wizard fails - Firewall Proxy

Tags: android-studio

So getting right to the point, I am behind a corporate firewall.  I had to manually download the zip file for Android Studio which I extracted to program files (windows 10) on my machine.  When I launch studio I'm dialogue'd studio needs to retrieve sdk's which I try to do but it fails on these 3 zips.

build-tools_r29.0.1-windows.zip

platform-29_r01.zip

sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip

Mostly  I see

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out Warning: An error
>   occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.1:
>   Read timed out.

I'm assuming my firewall proxy is preventing this type of setup install since the links to these zips point outside our network but  I am able to download the zips individually through a browser session one by one and save them here

c:\Users\myPin\AppData\Android\Sdk

I extracted each zip file and then reran Android Studio but it doesn't seem to have made any difference.  It still goes out trying to download the same packages which I already extracted to the SDK folder.  Shouldnt studio see the zips I've extracted in the SDK folder location?  How can I get this working?

Comment: Can you do it on a personal computer?

Comment: Yes but that computer is not behind a corporate proxy.

Comment: And you are downloading the .zip file and not the .exe file?

Comment: Yes, because I cannot download a Msi directly from the internet behind my corporate firewall.

Comment: Are your coworkers experiencing the same problem? Have any of them got it to work?

Comment: Yes, coworkers experience same problem.  It is definitely related to corporate firewall.  I can download the zips manually and extract them but even then it's still going to trying to grab xml's from google links I believe during installs and or setup of the sdk's.  I'm looking for a way to set this up behind corporate firewall which prevents that type of install.

Comment: The IDE still has its functionality right? Can you go into Preferences/Settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196825/discussion-between-insurgentpointerexception-and-puerto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have work around I think others might find useful.   If your having problems with the Gui SDK manager, then definitely use the cmd based sdk manager.  This did not time out for us.

So for example where in the Gui I would get something like

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

When tryin got get platform-29_r01.zip

[image: Example]

But if I try to perform the same operation using C:\Users\PIN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\Tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat using whatever cmd tool you like (I like cmder).

`.\sdkmanager.bat --proxy=http --proxy_host=access.lb.ssa.gov --proxy_port=80 "platforms;android-28" --verbose`

The above cmd will dl's and configure the sdk correctly.

[image: Cmd Results]

You may have to do this for any of the sdk's you require.  I think in our Firewall proxy scenario there's a user-agent setting or something that is not set for the Gui which is causing the timeouts but not with the cmd tools so this is a legitimate work around I think.

Comment: Just to add.  Spoke to our web gateway folks.  There was some tunnel funkiness between the dl.google.com stuff and our company.  With how we check things in the tunnel before they get set on to I think google was seeing that as man in the middle.  We'd have to add an exception and disable our checks in the tunnel to be able to use GUI SDK Setups which we have done.  But in the meantime you could try the above command line protocals if that is not an option in your org.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. You have to check your Computer time, it must be accurate. If still error appeared, try this.

On you PC search Powershell and type code below. See image below for reference.

[Path reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR4Zf.png)

[Powershell Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xll9X.png)

[Failed version code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J24qT.png)

[Click Retry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZdsH.png)

```
.\sdkmanager.bat --proxy=http --proxy_host=access.lb.ssa.gov --proxy_port=80 "platforms;android-29" --verbose
```

1. Run powershell > type cd> path of files
2. Check what SDK number version is getting error
3. From the android studio ERROR, click Retry while powershell is running.
4. If the said SDK version number is fixed, go to the next version number, by pressing control+C to powershell to stop the command.
5. Then type the same code with different number..

**Note: If you do not have bin folder. You can create a folder named bin and create sdkmanager.bat file, inside sdkmanager.bat file, type this code >> `sdkmanager.bat` and save.**