# i always see this error messgae when i'm installing andriod studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Whenever I try installing Android studio on my PC, I keep seeing this error message.
I have installed Android studio more than three times now,but I keep seeing this error message please any ways or suggestions . So that I can fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with your android studio package, but the network you're on while installing Android Studio. Before your start installation, connect to a reliable network also make sure to check your firewall settings while installing. However if you still face issues then refer below the similar asked question with solution.

Here is the [question with solution related to your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146952/android-studio-no-sdk-found-setup-wizard-fails-firewall-proxy)